# How clear JobRepository in Java EE Batch processing

Tags: jakarta-ee, batch-processing, wildfly

I have a batch processing job in my web app that requires 3 parameter on input. This job executes very often, few thousands times per day. Parameters on input in most cases are unique.
JobRepository store this parameters in heap. And after 10-12 thousands executions I have:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I can clear data in JobRepository by restarting wildfly server. 
How can I clean info about already executed jobs manualy from my app?

P.S.
I dont want to inrease heap size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ansver

```
BatchEnvironment batchEnvironment = null;
ServiceLoader<BatchEnvironment> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(BatchEnvironment.class);
for (Iterator<BatchEnvironment> it = serviceLoader.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    batchEnvironment = it.next();
    break;
}
JobRepository jobRepository = JobRepositoryFactory.getJobRepository(batchEnvironment);
jobRepository.removeJob("ourJobName");
```

Now info about all executions off this job will be lost. And the garbage collector can clean data about jobs from heap.

Comment: This is not in a release of WildFly yet, but there is a [batchlet](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/master/jberet-core/src/main/java/org/jberet/repository/PurgeBatchlet.java) you can use too.